# Passing functions/giving commands to ROS

Tags: c++, ros

I am new to ROS. I have no experience working with it. However, I have to work on one project where we have to implement RRT to ROS. Can anyone please explain me how to give commands to ROS or pass in parameters (I don't know what is the correct way to say this)? What I am trying to accomplish is, using C++, I want to get the x, y, and z values of the drone and then ask user (for now) for the new x, y, and z values and then update them so that the drone goes to those new values (or a point basically). I know how to code that in simple C++ but I am not sure if ROS follows the same structure. Here is an example of what I think how it would work in C++:

```
void getCurrentVals (float &x, float &y, float &z);
void updateVals (float x, float y, float z);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    float x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

    if (argc = 0)
      printf("The command had no other arguments.\n");

    getCurrentVals (x, y, z);

    cout << "x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "y: ";
    cin >> y;
    cout << "z: ";
    cin >> z;   

    updateVals (x, y, z);
}

void getCurrentVals (...){
    //get current vals using some code 
}

void updateVals (...) {
    //update vals somehow 
}
```

So my question is how to send/pass getCurrentVals and updateVals functions to in ROS to get those values and update them. Any help/suggetions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Because we have to use mav_comm and rotors_simulator from github @flatmouse

Comment: Start working through the [ROS tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials). Seeing as you are familiar with C++, you should be well up to speed after learning a few of the basic tutorials about the various concepts and programming techniques for ROS.